# How to get the cluster ID in Bisecting K-means method in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I've tried

```
 from numpy import array
 from pyspark.mllib.clustering import BisectingKMeans, BisectingKMeansModel
```

I'm using the iris.data set:

```
 iris_model.transform(iris)
```

but I get this error:

```
 AttributeError                            
 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-241-59b5e8c1e068> in <module>()
 ----> 1 iris_model.transform(iris)

AttributeError: 'BisectingKMeansModel' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

I can get the ClusterCenters and I get the array, but I need the group of which each case belongs to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mismatch Spark ML and MLlib APIs.

MLLib package was the first package, but then developers started to build new package, ML, which works with DataFrames.

Change your package to `pyspark.ml.clustering` and you will have new version, which has `transform` function and work with DataFrame and new ML Pipelines. I suggest yo build Pipeline when you will have algorithm working :)

Comment: I checked https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.BisectingKMeans                                                               from pyspark.ml.clustering import BisectingKMeans
dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("C:\spark\data\iris_data.txt")              and now I get this error:
----> 4 dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("C:\opt\spark\Untitled Folder\iris_data.txt")
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined

Comment: You must create your SparkSession https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession

Comment: I tried:    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyExample")\
        .getOrCreate()    But Now the new error error:C:\opt\spark\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"